# How to build a random number generator from a random number generator that generates 0 / 1

Tags: algorithm, random

A random number generator generates 0 or 1 with equal probability

How do you create another random number generator that can generate any integer betweeen 0 to N

Comment: Use the binary number system in combination with a hit and miss algorithm.

Comment: Most 'random' algorithms involve looking at the system clock or some enormous multiplication + modulo. True randomness can not really be programmed. Any well designed algorithm will do exactly what you instructed

Comment: What kind of biases can you tolerate? If you can't tolerate any then use @JohnColeman suggestion. If you can tolerate some bias then you might consider floor( N * (r/2\*\*k) ), where k is the bit length of N and r is an integer composed of k random bits drawn from your random method and the arithmetic inside the floor function is floating point.

Comment: @JohnColeman Could you explain a bit more on the implementation of how to do this?

Comment: @jameskpolk: "some bias" -> "some values are twice as likely as other values". Really, `k` should be quite a bit larger than log2 N in order to minimise the bias; it might as well be the word length assuming that the result of a multiplication is a doubleword.

Comment: @rici: Agreed. k should be as large as can reasonably be accomodated, small values of k result in too much bias.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to generate random numbers in the range 0 to 2^k - 1.
When n isn't a power of 2, you can find the smallest k with n < 2^k, and repeatedly generate random numbers in the range 0 to 2^k - 1 until you get one which is in fact < n. The expected number of trials before you get a hit is less than 2 (since k is chosen to be minimal, the probability of a hit is > 0.5) so this will be fairly efficient in practice. A Python implementation to flesh out these ideas:

```
from random import randint
from math import ceil,log

#a test function to generate random bits:
def rand2(): return randint(0,1)

def rand2n(n):
     #returns a random int in range 0 to 2^n - 1
     p = 1
     s = 0
     for i in range(n):
          if rand2() == 1:s += p
          p *= 2
     return s

def randn(n):
     #returns random int in range 0,...,n-1
     k = ceil(log(n,2))
     while True:
          x = rand2n(k)
          if x < n:
               return x #else, loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert N to binary. Get the number of bits(say n). Now generate n bits of random bits with the generator you have. Then convert the new number into decimal and divide by N. You will get something between 0 to N.

Comment: This will give you a biased result.  Generate n bits.  If the result is too large then throw it away and generate n more bits.  Repeat until the number is in the desired range.  That will eliminate the bias.

Comment: How can I know about the bias?

Comment: Say you want a number from 0 to 11.  4 bits will give you numbers from 0 to 15.  You need to drop results of 12, 13, 14 and 15.  If you try to use them, say with a `MOD 12`, then you will get 0, 1, 2, 3 more frequently than 4 to 11.  Code them both and look at the output from 10,000 runs of each.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.